# Oracle - Comparison with null warning

Tags: oracle

I have a function that uses a `cursor`, and this `cursor` is initialized by functions `paramenters`:

```
FUNCTION get_keys(p_1    IN VARCHAR) 
                  RETURN VARCHAR AS
p_result    VARCHAR(5000);

CURSOR crs_keys IS
  SELECT     key_name
  FROM       table_keys
  WHERE      key = '' || p_1 || '';

BEGIN
 p_result := '1';
 return p_result;
END get_key_columns;
```

While compiling, I get the waring:

```
comparison with null in get_keys
   WHERE      key = '' || p_1 || ''
```

I've already tried to set a default value in `p_1` and `'' || nvl(p_1, 'some test value') || ''`. But i can't get rid of this warning.

Thank you.

Comment: the function name does not match: get_keys vs. get_key_columns, I don't get that to compile at all on a 12c. Is that snippet complete?

Comment: why are you concatenating NULL ('') to p_1 in your cursor?  If you're trying to wrap p_1 in inverted commas you need to use ''''||p_1||'''' (but since p_1 is already a VARCHAR  I cannot see why you would want to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write,

```
WHERE key = '' || p_1 || '';
```

the two single quotes are an empty string which evaluates to NULL. And NULL concat something yields NULL.

Simply write,

```
WHERE key=p_1;
```

If the intention was to enclose the value of p_1 in literal quotes, do so by escaping the quotes, or require that the parameter that is passed in already has this in its value.

Comment: NULL concatenated with a string does not equal NULL.  SELECT ''||'f'||'' FROM dual will return f.

Comment: oops. right. that voids the first part of this answer. let's see if we get more information in OP about intention of that concat.

Comment: The solution was so obvious, but i could not see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized cursor it is better and more safe way.
Example

```
declare
      cursor test_cur(l_name in varchar) is
        select l_name from dual;
    l_out varchar(1024);


   begin
     open test_cur('John');
     loop
       fetch test_cur into l_out;

       if test_cur%notfound then
         close test_cur;
        exit;
      end if;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_out);
     end loop;
   end;
   /
```

Your modified code

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_keys(p_1    IN VARCHAR) 
                  RETURN VARCHAR AS
p_result    VARCHAR(5000);

CURSOR crs_keys(p_cur in varchar) IS
  SELECT     key_name
  FROM       table_keys
  WHERE      key = p_cur 
or (p_cur is null and key is null); --comparing with null

BEGIN
open crs_keys(p_1);
     loop
       fetch crs_keys into p_result;

       if crs_keys%notfound then
         close crs_keys;
        exit;
      end if;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_result);
     end loop;
 p_result := '1';
 return p_result;
END get_keys;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you - there's nothing intrinsically safer or better about cursor parameters.  There is nothing in the question to suggest a LOOP is appropriate (and if you want a loop, why not use a CURSOR FOR LOOP?)

Comment: It was just a quick example - please use CURSOR FOR LOOP or any other ways - up to you. It is just showed how to use parameters in cursor

Comment: Thanks for your answare, It will suit me in other occasions!